# Fetch with variables in constant of json body from react to python is not working

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to figure out why passing value if double-quotes works, but not when using variable, property or parameter.

The return is undefined object.

From POSTMAN all works fine.

Here is my fetch in react js (latest version):

```
  var currentdate = new Date(); 
  const datetime = currentdate.getDate() + ""
        + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + ""
        + currentdate.getFullYear() + ""
        + currentdate.getHours() + ""
        + (currentdate.getMinutes()-1)      
  const body = {
    ...
    numerator: datetime,
    ...
  };
  fetch(`${this.props.api}/data`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  })
```

Here is my python code:

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def set_dunction_data():
    if request.is_json:
        content = request.json
        data = dataapi.function1(...,content['numerator'],...)
        return make_response(jsonify(data),200)
```

This is my column definition using SQLAlchemy 1.1.3:

```
db.Column('numerator', db.String(500), nullable=True)
```

If I change

```
numerator: hash
```

to

```
numerator: "0" // or any other value with double-quotes
```

everything starts to work! Return is my expected value / json.

Why is that? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the uninitialized or null/undefined variable I attempted to use, that somehow slipped off the eyesight :/